# Getting "Channel number out of range" error when altering table using after keyword

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a MariaDB table with some foreign keys and triggers. For some reason I'm getting an error when I try to alter it using the AFTER keyword.

If I run this:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` ADD COLUMN baz VARCHAR(190) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `bar`;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 44 "Channel number out of range" from storage engine InnoDB

Yet if I run this:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` ADD COLUMN baz VARCHAR(190) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

It works but (as expected) doesn't organize the columns in the order I need.

Any idea how to get this to work using the column order I need?

**Update:**

I haven't figured out the issue yet but I did try making alterations with the AFTER keyword to other tables and it turns out the issue occurs specifically with this one table, other tables function properly.

Comment: Perhaps we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was occurring because the MariaDB was running on a Windows filesystem shared via WSL into a Docker container (`/mnt/c/Git/my_project`).

To fix it, the entire container was moved into the WSL filesystem (`~/my_project`) and then the ALTER command with the AFTER keyword worked fine.

Comment: In my case, I restart the DB container and everything works fine again. I'm using docker in WSL2.

Comment: for those who use laradock, update this mariadb setting inside docker-compose.yml:


      volumes:
        - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        #- ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        #- ${MARIADB_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d